# a python script to snmpget in bulk

Tags: python, snmp

I've written a script to read ip addresses from a txt file (iplist.txt) and run snmpget on them one by one & display the output. Now I need some help directing the output to another txt file (result.txt) in the following format:

127.0.0.1: snmpget result1

127.0.0.2: snmpget result2

& so on

## here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
snmp = "snmpget -v2c -c 'xyz' "
OID = " sysName.0"
iplist = "iplist.txt"
with open(iplist) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.rstrip(" ")
        command = os.system(str(snmp + line + OID))
```

## print command

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post some code showing what you've tried already. We're not here to code for you on command. Good luck!

Comment: I recommend using http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi, sorry guys, I've edited my post & added my code!

Comment: Redirecting anything on the command line to a file works with `command > target_filename`. You don't really need t change your script for that. Concentrate on making python print the output format you want and let the shell handle the creation of the file.

Comment: is there an easy way to do it from inside the script? and also to clear the file content every time the script runs before writing the results there!?